# Override View path in the Controller is only partially working

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, view, controller

In my main controller, I'm successfully incorporating a custom path for the *Model*, but seem to be missing something for the custom path to the *View*.

The component path is:

```
\components
    \com_meetings
        \models
            \meetings
                meetings.php          (Joomla Default)
            \custom
                \meetings
                    meetings.php      (My custom override that works)
        \views
            \meetings                 (Joomla Default)
                \tmpl
                view.html.php          
            \custom                   (My Custom views Folder)
                \meetings             (Customized View)
                    \tmpl             (This folder is ignored)
                    view.html.php     (This DOES load)
```

So, with the below code, Joomla *does* properly load the custom Model but only *partially* loads the custom view.  (My `view.html.php` is loaded, but the relevant `\tmpl` folder is ignored and it reverts back to the default `\tmpl`.

**com_meetings\controller.php:** (Joomla 3.6.2)

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
class MeetingsController extends JControllerLegacy {
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        $this->input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

        // Begin Custom Model and View Paths
        $view_name          = $this->input->getCmd('view', $this->default_view);
        // Custom Model Path
        $custom_model_path  = JPATH_COMPONENT.'/models/custom/';
        $custom_model       = $custom_model_path.$view_name.'.php';
        if(is_dir( $custom_model_path )){
            if(file_exists( $custom_model )){
                $config['model_path'] = $custom_model_path;
            }
        }
        // Custom View Path
        $custom_view_path   = JPATH_COMPONENT.'/views/custom/';
        if(is_dir( $custom_view_path )){
            $custom_view_path   .= $view_name;
            if(is_dir( $custom_view_path )){
                $custom_view        = $custom_view_path.'/view.html.php';
                if(file_exists( $custom_view )){
                    $config['view_path'] = JPATH_COMPONENT.'/views/custom';
                }
            }
        }
        // End Custom View Path

        parent::__construct($config);
    }
```

The above paths ARE considered in the `__construct()` method of `libraries\fof\controller\controller.php` around line 594 and 617, and does load my `view.html.php`, but as mentioned the relative `\tmpl` folder is being ignored.

```
Line 594   if (array_key_exists('model_path', $config))....
Line 617   if (array_key_exists('view_path', $config))
```

**views\custom\meetings\view.html.php**

```
class MeetingsViewMeetings extends JViewLegacy {
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) {
        throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
    }

    $this->_prepareDocument();
    \\ The override gets this far;
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

I can't follow where this is being checked, and can't see what I've done wrong.  Any suggestions are welcomed~

P.S., I know I can put override views in the template, but I want to implement the custom path of Joomla at the component level to retain the customizations regardless of what Template may be active.

**ADDITONAL UPDATE**
When looking at the $view, I see that it has resolved the paths to check for.  So I guess the question is how to get my custom path between these 2:

```
[_path:protected] => Array (
        [template] => Array (
                [0] => C:\www\commission\templates\protostar\html\com_meetings\meetings\
                [1] => C:\www\commission\components\com_meetings\views\meetings\tmpl\
            )
    )
[_template:protected] => C:\www\commission\components\com_meetings\views\meetings\tmpl\default.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to path 'template_path' in the config as well. Probably something like

```
$config['template_path'] = array(
    JPATH_COMPONENT.'/views/tmpl',
    $custom_view_path.'/tmpl',
    /* maybe other override place here like the template */
);
```

I don't think any of the autogenerated paths match your file structure (lines 2703 to 2725).

```
    if (!array_key_exists('template_path', $config))
    {
        $config['template_path'][] = $componentPaths['main'] . '/views/' . FOFInflector::pluralize($config['view']) . '/tmpl';

        if ($templateOverridePath)
        {
            $config['template_path'][] = $templateOverridePath . '/' . FOFInflector::pluralize($config['view']);
        }

        $config['template_path'][] = $componentPaths['main'] . '/views/' . FOFInflector::singularize($config['view']) . '/tmpl';

        if ($templateOverridePath)
        {
            $config['template_path'][] = $templateOverridePath . '/' . FOFInflector::singularize($config['view']);
        }

        $config['template_path'][] = $componentPaths['main'] . '/views/' . $config['view'] . '/tmpl';

        if ($templateOverridePath)
        {
            $config['template_path'][] = $templateOverridePath . '/' . $config['view'];
        }
    }
```